# Using wpdb to display non-wordpress database data not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have created a section in my functions.php file and registered a shortcode which is intended to echo some data from a custom mysql database table.
I have an external system which will insert data into the database.
My wordpress install should be able to read from this database, and I would like to echo some rows on a wordpress page via shortcode.
The problem I am having is that the table data is not being echoed out. I can do echo "test"; and the word test will get displayed but the problem I having is not showing table data. Heres my code.

```
function vstp_feed_function(){
    //$x++;
    //$alternatingclass = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'graybackground';
    $mydb = new wpdb('root','cencored','testdb','localhost');
    $rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from services");
        echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($rows as $obj) :
                 echo "<li>".$obj->headcode."</li>";
            endforeach;
        echo "</ul>";

}
add_shortcode('vstp_feed', 'vstp_feed_function');
```

So the above code will create a new variable mydb, with the database credentials and information. A new variable called $rows will store the sql query which uses the mydb variable. I get all columns from services table. Thereafter I am echoing an unordered list, running a for loop to display the contents of the column "headcode" in list item html.
Once the select query is done, the for loop ends and so does the html list.
The shortcode is registered as [vstp_feed] which is tested and working with static html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Worked with sql before but not with new wordpress db instances. Thanks.

Just to confirm, its apache ubuntu. Its also worth noting that my @@datadir is stored on a different disk seperate from my OS disk, for faster IO and freedom to expand storage on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your connection code inside wp-config.php file ( $mydb = new wpdb('root','cencored','testdb','localhost'); )

And use it in your function file as "global $mydb;"

Comment: Thanks, im very sorry but I have just realised that my database connection had the wrong password in it XD Everything is working fine now. Thank you for taking the time to have a look at my query.